# Cannot run Webpack Intro - webpack-dev-server

Tags: angular, webpack

I worked through the introduction at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html and I am able to build and run in production mode. I am having trouble getting the dev mode I get

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080

70% 1/1 build modulesC:\angular2-webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:72
                   var elements = request.replace(/^-?!+/, "").replace(/!!+/g, "!").split("!");
                                         ^
ypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Any pointers here will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run it by removing --inline from the above command in dev mode. I also faced the same problem but it worked for me when I tried running it without --inline  in dev mode..

Comment: That's not the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

The **webpack.config.js** was missing! Pull latest and try again. 
Mine started working.

[Refer This](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/120) for the issue